# How to stop tinyMCE 5 to add ../../../../ before an absolute url received from alexusmai filemanager?

Tags: laravel-5, file-manager, tinymce-5

I am using Laravel 8, tinyMCE 5 and Alexusmai filemanager.  My images are in the /public/assets/images folder.
The 'assets' disk is setup in config/filesystems.php :

```
    // assets folder in public path
    'assets' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('assets'),
        'url' => '/public/assets',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
```

FM returns the correct relatrive url, i.e. public/assets/images/xxx.jpg in a form field as a stand alone.

In tinyMCE 5, the same url is returned to the editor (the image is visible) but as soon as I look in the source3 code, the img scr is replaced by "../../../../public/assets/images/xxx.jpg".  Why?  How can I stop tiny to do that?

update...

It also seems that sometimestiny only adds ../ before public/assets... which results in the image not showing in the editor but displaying correctly in the website page.  Weird!

How can I stop that please...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is TinyMCE's "url handling": https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

Try to add `convert_urls: false` to `tinymce.init`